# Excel advanced lookup/reference formula required

Tags: indexing, reference, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I am not sure which function is needed, either Vlookup or Match to bring a value from one report to another.  For example, I am trying to introduce these values into another report that is more comprehensive and includes more categories.  I am looking for a formula that would correctly identify a value such as the quantity of Hot Tea but also take into consideration the header of Morning versus Evening as the results are quite different and thus a plain vlookup won't work.

Chart 1

`Morning             |       Quantity
Hot tea             |          10
Hot pie             |          15
Mac and Cheese      |          20
Afternoon           |
Hot chocolate       |          30
Hot pie             |          35
Mac and Cheese      |          40
Evening             |
Hot tea             |          25
Croissants          |          20
Broccoli            |          20`

Chart 2

`Morning       |Quantity    |Regular    | No Trans Fat     |No Corn Syrup
Hot tea      |   10        |    3       |   2              |    5
Hot pie      |   15        |    5       |   2              |    8
Mac and Cheese|  20        |    15      |   5              |    0 
Afternoon

Hot chocolate |  30        |    25      |   2              |    3
Hot pie       |  35        |    30      |   5
Mac and Cheese|  40        |    38      |   1              |    1
Evening

Hot tea       |  25        |    20      |   2              |    3
Croissants    |  20        |    17      |   2              |    1
Broccoli      |  20        |    16      |   1              |    3`

Answer (score 0):

allright you need to have a work around so here's my suggestion.  let's pretend that your table starts at A1 with Morning.  C1 i want you to type "Morning"

then in C2 use this formula

```
=IF(B2="",A2,C1)
```

then drag down to the end of your list and you should get something like this

[image]

Now not knowing what your other sheet looks like the last part you may need to rework. but i would set up a table like this

[image]

and in cell B2 use this formula

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$C:$C,B$1)
```

and drag to fill up rest of the table.  like i said not knowing how you're table us set up it's difficult to say

Comment: Thanks Chris for the detailed answer!  The problem is that I have additional criterium in columns B, C, D, etc. such as hypothetically Regular  Low Fat Sugar Sweetener.  I was planning to control for this by adjusting the range in the formula when importing from the other report.

Comment: i assume you meant James,

how about 

    Hot Tea|Morning
    Hot Tea|Noon
    Hot Tea|Evening
    Coffee|Morning
    etc

change the formula to 

=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A1,Sheet1!$C:$C,$A2)

and expand to include the other columns.

if not perhaps post a format that you would like the data to be in.
Note sometimes that's the hardest part.

Comment: James!  Million apologies - I saw edited by Chris.  I really don't have the option of changing the headers because we pull the data from a report generated elsewhere.  This is what the format of the data is:

Comment: How do I input a picture of what my data looks like?  I don't see an option to paste nor upload. Thanks! @James Chen

Comment: you may have to do an edit on your original post.  i think you can only attach pictures in Answers and the original post.  Please someone correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: You are right, James.  You can only add images to answers and the original post and "You need at least 10 reputation to post images".  Thus, I attempt to recreate that table above @James Chen

Comment: This is the format of the report that I receive and cannot edit, and thus mine is structured the same only much more comprehensive (and I do not have flexibility to change mine either based on the end audience).  I am looking for a formula the equivalent of vlookup but one that distinguish between "hot tea" consumed in the morning versus the evening in total, regular and no sugar :).  Thanks again!

Comment: wait, you want the data from sheet 1 to go to the 2nd one you posted right?  How would the data in Sheet1 give you the breakout you in sheet 2 if sheet 1 only gives you total qty?

Comment: Please ignore chart 1.  I just tried to simplify it but then you suggest expanding the headers into the columns.  I am trying to import from a report that has the same headers only my report is way more detailed as it has more categories.